# how to update the Athena tables and show previous values as well has the current value for a column in aws quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am able to create tables in Athena using the glue crawler (files coming from s3 as csv) and every time that csv file's values get updated, the crawler runs again and the table's values are shown as updated.

I display this result in aws quicksight, that this x item has x price. But now I want to show the previous prices of the item and the current price in quicksight. for example something like :

October $15

November $20

December $30

how can I achieve this without creating new tables every time the CSV changes, because otherwise there would be so many tables created at one point?

Comment: what I'm thinking of doing is having a new table where the rows are months and in the columns, I have things like item and price. so that the months stay fixed and items and prices can of course keep changing. I think this way i would show each month what item is having different prices in quicksight. please let me know if this solution works and also if there is a better solution.

Comment: Your comment above is the correct approach.